How to give spans a height without breaking lines?
I am trying to display nested spans, each span with its own height and underlining, so a user can differentiate between the different spans.
See this jsfiddle
The example also shows how the "weduwe [..] Bouwensz" span breaks the line within the .pane, which should not happen. I only want the 'ordinary' line breaks on words.
I could comment out these two lines:
.nested-annotation {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  /* white-space: nowrap;   */

But then all the underlines collapse because the spans lose their margin.
How can I prevent these span-line breaks, without the spans losing their height and the underlines collapsing into a single line?


.pane {
  width: 40em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.nested-annotation {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.nested-annotation:hover {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

.underlined-hoe {
  border-bottom-color: #b84040 !important;
}

.underlined-per {
  border-bottom-color: rgb(159, 202, 4) !important;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pane">Synde ter vergaderinge gelesen de requeste van <span class="annotated-segment"><span class="underlined-hoe nested-annotation">weduwe van wylen den <span class="underlined-per nested-annotation">Capn. Willem Bouwensz</span></span>
    </span> om te hebben betalinge van twee ordonnantien om hare betalinge aldaer te vorderen.</div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




I'm not sure to understand the question: do you want the div to keep line breaking or do you really want everything in a single line ? because white-space: no-wrap on the .pane class works well to keep everything on a single line

Yes, I would like the text to be breaking inside the pane (so you can see all the text without scrolling), but not on the spans (just the words). When setting nowrap, the text inside the pane is not broken on anything anymore, and it turns into one single line, which is not what I want.

When downvoting, please let me know why: I think there is a real question here, but maybe I have to reword it a bit.

Nothing more frustrating than a downvote without explanations

It is difficult to understand what you want. Could you provide screenshots/sketches of what you want to happen and not to happen?

Add this style to span
min-width: fit-content;

Hope it helps
